# Borrar la rama secundaria de github para poder crear otra y arreglar un problema que tengo

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Creé una rama pero el último cambio de master no se pasó a esta (ya lo tenía pusheado y todo).
Quiero borrar esta rama para intentarlo otra vez, la cuestión es que ya tengo un commit pusheado en la rama secundaria, entonces: si borro la rama, ¿se borra y desaparece de Github? ¿O cómo lo hago? Porque no quiero que quede rastro de la rama secundaria.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de resolverlo sería que crees un PR para mezclar desde la rama secundaria a `master`. Una vez que hayas hecho la mezcla, puedes borrar la rama secundaria. Otra forma sería empujar lo de la rama secundaria directamente a `master`:

```
git push origin rama-secundaria:master
```

Ahí lo que le estás diciendo a git es que empuje de tu rama **local** llamada `rama-secundaria` a la rama remota `master`. Si no tienes protección de la rama `master` habilitado, ese push no debería dar problemas, a menos que la historia se haya bifurcado porque también tienes commits en `master`.... en ese caso te tocaría hacer un merge o un rebase (o un `pull`) para entonces poder hacer el `push`.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @JonathanGarcia si te fue útil, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta.

Comment: @padaleiana muchas gracias por estar pendiente. En realidad no estoy pendiente de si le hacen upvotes o aceptan las respuestas (en muchas ocasiones solo recivo un upvote....... y no entiendo por qué ya que se que hay varias personas que están pendientes de las preguntas sobre `git` y que sabrían que una respuesta es apropiada).... espero estar ganando karma, por lo menosa :-D

Comment: Mi comentario es nada más para que la misma pregunta no vuelva a aparecer una y otra vez en el inicio, siendo que ya tiene una (o varias) respuestas válidas :) Pero sí, en cuanto a lo que mencionaste, con suerte y uno recibe votos a favor en una buena respuesta.

Comment: Es cierto.... yo he hecho algunos upvotes para ti (creo) pero como solo miro preguntas sobre git, no es que salga mucho material para votar :-D.